# Axios post request to Firebase Auth REST API produces 400 error

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, axios

I have an instance of Axios:

```js
import axios from 'axios';

const instance = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1'
});

export default instance;
```

Then I import it in my signup.vue file:

```js
<script>
  import axios from '../../axios-auth';
  ...
</script>
```

In that Vue file I have a signup form, which runs the following method once I hit the Submit button:

```js
onSubmit() {
        const formData = {
          email: this.email,
          age: this.age,
          password: this.password,
          confirmPassword: this.confirmPassword,
          country: this.country,
          hobbies: this.hobbyInputs.map(hobby => hobby.value),
          terms: this.terms
        };
        console.log(formData);
        axios.post('/accounts:signUp?key=my_key_goes_here', {
          email: formData.email,
          password: formData.password,
          returnSecureToken: true
        })
          .then(res => {
            console.info(res);
          })
          .catch(error => {
            console.error(error);
          });
      }
```

I'm getting a <s>403 error - forbidden</s> 400 error - bad request.

I tried to change headers:

```js
instance.defaults.headers.post["Access-Control-Allow-Origin"] = "localhost";
instance.defaults.headers.common["Content-Type"] = "application/json";
```

But that didn't help.

I'm working from localhost and I saw that localhost is allowed by default. I tried also to add 127.0.0.1 to the list, but that also didn't help.

What am I missing? How can I make this request work?

Comment: Access-Control-Allow-Origin is a response header. It must be set on the server side, not in your frontend JavaScript code that makes the request. And if you’re getting a 403 response, it’s expected it won’t have the Access-Control-Allow-Origin response header. Typically, servers only add your application-set headers to success responses — 2xx and maybe 3xx responses — but not to 4xx or 5xx error responses. And any CORS configuration you do is never going to cause the server to respond with a 403. So whatever is actually causing the 403 error, it’s not related to CORS configuration, at all.

Comment: @sideshowbarker I saw an error message saying it was CORS. For some reason now I don't see it, but now I have a 400 error - bad request. I see the request goes to `https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signUp?key=my_api_key` which is, according to Firebase docs, should be the API endpoint.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you get a 400 error it is maybe because you get an error from the [API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth#section-create-email-password) itself:

> **Common error codes**
>
> EMAIL_EXISTS: The email address is already in use by another account.
>
> OPERATION_NOT_ALLOWED: Password sign-in is disabled for this project.
>
> TOO_MANY_ATTEMPTS_TRY_LATER: We have blocked all requests from this device due to unusual activity. Try again later.

As a matter of fact, those errors return an HTTP Status Code of 400.

You can see the exact response message (e.g. `EMAIL_EXISTS`) by doing the following with axios:

```
    axios.post('/accounts:signUp?key=my_key_goes_here', {
      email: formData.email,
      password: formData.password,
      returnSecureToken: true
    })
      .then(res => {
        console.info(res);
      })
    .catch(error => {
      if (error.response) {
        // The request was made and the server responded with a status code
        // that falls out of the range of 2xx
        console.log(error.response.data);
      } else if (error.request) {
        console.log(error.request);
      } else {
        console.log("Error", error.message);
      }

    });
```

See https://github.com/axios/axios#handling-errors

Comment: Thank you, that did help! Apparently, since I'm only testing it, I was using a weak password, only 3 chars, while Firebase requires a minimum of 6 chars. Once changed to 6 - worked like a charm. Again, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I agree with you as i have tried many approaches but was not getting the result. Hence i have tried to change the code.

You need to make two changes in your code.

1] You need to comment `the instance.defaults.headers.post["Access-Control-Allow-Origin"] = "localhost";` because you are providing the authentication globally. As, firebase provides the feature of authentication and you are connecting the web app with REST API.

2] You need to add `{ headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json' }`  in the axios.post() method to prevent it from CORS Error.
Following this approach i hope you can get the respective output.
Happy Coding!

Answer (score 0):

Directly call
[https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signUp?key=[yourkey]](https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signUp?key=%5Byourkey%5D)

No need to keep it in a separate file

Answer (score 0):

Anyone who comes to the thread in future. I faced this issue and lost in debugging and worked with fetch. It was tiresome and took me a day but i made axios work. Here is the code.
const data = JSON.stringify({
idToken: authContext.token,
password: enteredNewPassword,
returnSecureToken: false,
});

```
// Send the valid password to the endpoint to change password
axios
  .post(
    "https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:update?key=[Your Key]",
    data,
    {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
    }
  )
  .then((response) => {
    console.log(response.data);
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err.message);
  });
```

- Remember to **Stringify** the data you want to send. Stringify it outside of the http request and then pass that variable. Don't know why but this helps!
- Lastly remember to add the header when sending the request to firebase. Make sure axios.post is on the same line. My formatter gave a line break which was also cause of error.
- Hope it helps :)